# PostgreSQL: LISTEN with insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one notify function and trigger as below

Here I am inserting records before notification `listerner_to_insert_code(resVal)`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.codes_notify_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
      resVal text;
    BEGIN
       resVal := row_to_json(NEW);
     select listerner_to_insert_code(resVal);

       PERFORM pg_notify('code_channel', resVal::text);

       RETURN new;
     END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER codeInsertTrigger
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON public.codings
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.codes_notify_trigger();
```

Then I can't see the payloads on

When I tried

```
LISTEN code_channel
```

But I can see the payloads if I remove `select listerner_to_insert_code(resVal)`

Here in below it will show the payloads

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.codes_notify_trigger()
      RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
        DECLARE
          resVal text;
        BEGIN
           resVal := row_to_json(NEW);

           PERFORM pg_notify('code_channel', resVal::text);

           RETURN new;
         END;
        $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

But I want to insert record after LISTEN.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error `query has no destination for result data`. Check your logs to make sure.

When using SELECT in PL/pgSQL code, you need to do something with returned data, like for example INSERT it into table or variable(s).

If you don't want to do anything with returned data, then use `PERFORM` instead.

`PERFORM listerner_to_insert_code(resVal);`